# How to set end index of numpy array relative to start index

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Is it possible to index a numpy array such that the first index is the start index and the second index is the number of samples/indices to grab relative to the start index?

```
   a = np.arange(10)
   b = a[3:7]      # b=[3,4,5,6] 
   c = a[3:+4]     # desired, take 4 samples from index 3
```

Comment: `a[i : i + x]`, start at `i`, grab `x`.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but, I want to avoid cascading variables as described. The code  will have several subsequent calls and it will get a bit out of hand.

Comment: What about `a[i:][:x]`.

Comment: @MrGeek - Yes! That works, not as pretty, but that's workable. Want to put it as an answer and I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either `a[i : i + x]` or `a[i:][:x]`, where the indexing starts at `i` and grabs `x` elements.